# Flutter RawScrollbar track color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I try customise my Scrollbar in Flutter.
I can change `thumbColor`, but how to change track colour?
My code:

```dart
Container(
        height: 300.0,
        width: 300.0,
        child: RawScrollbar(
          
          thumbColor: MyStyle.myColorNavigation,
          thickness: 11,
          radius: Radius.circular(5),
          // showTrackOnHover: true,
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 15,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('Placeholder'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: anyone please help..I'm also facing same issue..

Comment: @saddam I am also having the issue. Did u solved this? If so please post the answer. According to the docs the track visiblity and thumb visibility should be set to true inorder to get it to work, but none of them seems to work on my end.

Comment: @saddam and also when I went through the flutter code, I saw that irrepective of what color we send from the api, it always set a constant color. I think thats the main issue

Comment: sorry @SVG i didn't found any solution..

Comment: @saddam I found a solution. But for that you want to change the raw scrollbar inside flutter. Once you ship it it will be fine.

Comment: @SVG can You explain Your solution?

Comment: yeah @SVG can you Explain your solution..

Comment: @saddam , Actually its a workaround, If we really want to stick with the rawscrollbar track color change then probably we need to change the framework code related to track color change. Or else what we can do is set the track color to transparent and using a stack widget, create a rectangular container and on top of that place the scrollbar widget. In some cases specially in IOS depending on how the screen is been designed, raw scrollbar adds an extra margin in the bottom, So make sure you wrap the entire widget class with a media query with a padding of 0 in the bottom.

Comment: And really sorry for taking time to reply :(

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to change the trackColor you have to change Scrollbar with RawScrollBar and add values such as:

trackVisibility: true,
trackColor: 'YOUR COLLOR',